# PHP.ini overriding/not allowing set_ini or set_include_path directives

Tags: path, include, php

I'm not exactly sure why this is happening. I'm running MAMP on my local machine. And I decided to install PEAR locally. So I edited the PHP.ini file and uncommented the include_path directive. Now for some reason none of my ini_set or set_include path directives work:

```
// trying to different methods
ini_set( 'include_path', ini_get( 'include_path' ) . PATH_SEPARATOR . BASE_PATH . "Zend/library/" );
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . BASE_PATH . "Zend/library/" );
```

Here's my php.ini directive:

```
include_path = ".:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/lib/php:/usr/local/PEAR"
```

If I comment that out then my code works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you 1000000% sure you have the right php.ini? Check `phpinfo()`

Comment: Yeah I've edited it a bunch. And when I uncomment and comment out that line it effects what I'm doing ...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using WAMP on my PC at work. I can't be certain if it is the same, but looking at the MAMP download page, it might well be.

I edited the php.ini files but the changes weren't taking effect. After a little bit of tinkering, I found out that when the services start, they don't use the ini files in their expected locations. Modifying the php.ini file made no effect. However, when I clicked the WAMP system icon, and chose the *Modify PHP.ini* option, it opened a new php.ini file in notepad - which I was able to *Save* but surprisingly not *Save As*. This leads me to understand that the ini files for WAMP, and quite likely MAMP are dynamically created on the fly and not using the files that are stored physically in the folder structure.